# Are there caveats when defining the Activity context as an Class field?

Tags: android

What are the caveats of defining the context as an Class field?

```
public class FooActivity extends Activity {
    private final Context context = FooActivity.this;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Did you mean a static variable in your code?

Comment: Why do you want to create construction like this? When you are in the scope of Activity class, you can simply use "this" keyword to access Activity Context.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen No idea, I was cargo culting code I had seen before. I'll just use this from now on instead of FooActivity.this

Comment: @PuercoPop In some cases, you can use FooActivity.this. E.g. when you are in the scope of a listener implementation or something similar and you cannot access Activity context easily, but in most cases "this" keyword is sufficient. Nevertheless, assignment of FooActivity.this to the context field is not necessary.